# is this a Context free Language : $L=\{W_1W_2 \mid W_1 \ne W_2 \: \text{and} \: |W_1|=|W_2|\}$

Tags: automata, context-free, pushdown-automata

$L=\{W_1W_2 \mid W_1 \ne W_2 \: \text{and} \: |W_1|=|W_2|\}$

Alphabet = { a , b }*

Considering L={WW} is not context free, shouldn't this be non context free as well? otherwise can you provide a machine or grammar which accepts this?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/81708/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2446349/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: @TeamBright please do not edit closed questions, if you add LaTeX support, the question gets bumped to reopen queue. After your edit the queston is still duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classical example of a context-free language whose complement is not context-free. It is context-free since every word in $w$ has the form
$$ \Sigma^i a \Sigma^j \Sigma^i b \Sigma^j = \Sigma^i a \Sigma^i \Sigma^j b \Sigma^j $$
or the similar form with the locations of $a$ and $b$ switched.

Comment: Do you know any source which has drawn the PDA for this language ? or at least the grammar ?! thanks.

Comment: I think you have enough information to work them out yourself.

Comment: I don't even understand what is that equation you wrote, that doesn't make any sense?

Comment: Well, take it as a hint. It's an identity of languages or regular expressions. You can also look for previous instances of your question on this site.